# Not able to deploy the Web App: "library with identifier is missing" error

Tags: google-apps-script

I have deleted some older versions under file -> manage versions, keeping only the latest version.

[image: Manager Versions Tab Image]]

After that, it is not loading the project properties and also not able to deploy the webapp.

[image: Project properties not loading]]

When i tried to deploy the webapp, it is giving following error.

> Library with identifier {project_name} is missing (perhaps it was deleted, or you don't have read access?)

Can anyone help, where it went wrong.

Comment: Can you paste manifest.json?(Find "Show manifest file' in menu if it's not there). If your script is dependant on missing libs(e.g. removed scripts) you might get this error

Comment: @roma Thanks. It worked now. After removing the dependant libraries, Now deploy as webapp is working fine.